# rotate svg matrix3d transform in 180º firefox and opera yes

Tags: css, animation, svg, css-animations

The animations rotate a 3D matrix svg keyframe in "firefox" flaw in the browser 180 and "operates" when performed. Someone might tell me that '?

```
enter code here
```

CODE LINES SO MUCH WHY PUT LINK

See the Pen [firefox no realiza bien la animacion a 180ª???](http://codepen.io/mateos1/pen/XKrxPG/) by jose manuel mateos terren ([@mateos1](http://codepen.io/mateos1)) on

Comment: Questions have to be written in English here. Would you be happier here instead? http://spanish.stackexchange.com/ Also the code needs to be in the question itself and not just a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First my apologies for using google translator.
My question is :
as you can change the way of doing the keyframes priate use transformatrix to perform in a circular interpolation matrix